# Python library to get the GPU fan speed

Tags: python, ubuntu, monitoring, gpu, nvidia

I am looking for a Python library that can get the GPU's fan speed. It should work on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS x64 and support Nvidia GPUs.

Comment: There is this python script that plots Nvidia GPU's usage, maybe with some adjustments it can work for you https://github.com/panch13114/gpumonitor

Comment: you might want to check this out https://code.google.com/p/nvidia-fanspeed/